# Failed to log in: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cancel'

Tags: python, cassandra, datastax, opscenter

[image: !!LOGIN ERROR !!]I am trying to login in Cassandra Opscenter i started seeing this message.How to get around this.

I was able to login yesterday also but from today morning i couldn't. I started seeing this error in opscenterd log file.

```
Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 388, in errback
        self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 455, in _startRunCallbacks
        self._runCallbacks()
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 542, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1076, in gotResult
        _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1018, in _inlineCallbacks
        result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
      File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py-redhat/2.6/shared/amd64/twisted/python/failure.py", line 349, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
        return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/opscenterd/WrappedDriver.py", line 102, in _defer_to_pool

    opscenterd.WrappedDriver.NoHostAvailable: Unable to complete the operation against any hosts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refreshing browser hasn't helped but Restarting opscenterd service on opscenter node has helped in fixing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an instance of a bug we're tracking as OPSC-5380.  Fortunately there is a workaround: refreshing your browser should allow you to login again.